# Maven Surefire is merging all suite reports in one Extent Report

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, maven-surefire-plugin, extentreports

I'm running multiple suite files in testng.xml from the surefire plugin. I'm using Extent reporting. When I run the testng.xml separately, each suite creates a separate HTML Extent report. But when I run from pom.xml, all the test cases are merged into one HTML Extent report.

Here's the pom.xml

```
<plugin>
                                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                    <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>                 
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <properties>
                    <property>
                      <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
                      <value>false</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                    <name>suitethreadpoolsize</name>
                    <value>2</value>
                    </property></properties>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

And here's the testng.xml

```
<suite name="Suites">
  <suite-files>
 
  <suite-file  path ="src/test/java/housekeeping/Employee/plan/Employee_NP.xml"></suite-file>
   <suite-file  path ="src/test/java/AccountReceivable/propertyARAccounts/testPlan/PropertyARAccounts_SI.xml"></suite-file>
  
  </suite-files>
</suite>
```